# Maya calendar closes after start

Tags: calendar

Every time I start Maya it instantly closes again. Is there anything I can do about that?
I installed all automatically received updates.

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 15:44:16.552528] Application.vala:155: Kalender version: 0.3.1.1
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 15:44:16.552581] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-39-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 15:44:16.789360] maya_util_is_the_all_day: assertion 'dtend != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 15:44:16.789426] Kalender will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 15:44:16.789471] [GLib] g_date_time_format: assertion 'datetime != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 15:44:16.789494] Kalender will not function properly. Segmentation fault (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Comment: Try launch it from terminal and copy&paste the output

Comment: This is what the Terminal tells me after launching Maya

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known bug, reported 2015-02-10,  but in undecided state. You can follow it at

[Maya at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1420431)

There are some workaround solutions that you can try at:

[Maya bug no. 1388515](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1388515)

See comments #11 and #13.

You can mark it as affect to you, in order to find a solution by Maya dev team.

Comment: I tried the mentioned workarounds, but they don't seem to work. I will try again in the afternoon... The problem seems to be linked to the google calendar somehow, because maya works in offline mode...

Comment: Remember report the bug. Greetings

Comment: Have you tried to configure your Google Calendar via CalDav?

Comment: Yes I tried, with the same result. Maya instantly crashes. I also tried the http - https thing thats explained in comment #13

Comment: I've reported the bug at launchpad along with the above mentioned Terminal output. Let's see what happens next! Thank you for your help!